# Ionic platform should install on npm install

Tags: android, angular, cordova, npm, ionic3

I created a new Ionic project, then added the `Android` platform using `ionic cordova platform add android`. This will write an entry in the `config.xml` file:

```
<engine name="android" spec="~6.1.2" />
```

Also before, I saw some places that we can save the platform in the `package.json`, so I put it there too:

```
"cordovaPlatforms": [
    "android",
    {
      "platform": "android",
      "version": "",
      "locator": "android"
    }
  ]
```

Now if I commit all of this, then clone the repo on a different computer, and run `npm install`, it does not add the android platform. And if I try to run `ionic cordova platform add android` again, it tells me that the platform already exists.

Am I missing a configuration for the platform to be added automatically when I install on a new machine? or do I really need to remove the platform and add it again every time?

My `ionic info`:

```
cli packages: (/Users/guillaumeroyer/Documents/workspace/ionic-2-events-demo/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.1
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.1

global packages:

    Cordova CLI : 6.5.0 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.4
    Cordova Platforms  : none
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.0.2
    ios-deploy        : 1.9.1 
    ios-sim           : 5.0.13 
    Node              : v7.4.0
    npm               : 4.1.2 
    OS                : macOS Sierra
    Xcode             : Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cordova prepare`.It copies assets to Cordova platforms, preparing them for native builds.

```
ionic cordova prepare 
ionic cordova prepare ios
ionic cordova prepare android
```

You can see the [**details here**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/prepare/)

Comment: Does the `cordova prepare` command also install the platforms if they're listed in the `package.json` file but missing in the project folder?

Comment: Yes, It does that too and more stuff http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/prepare/ @sebaferreras

Comment: Oh yeah `ionic cordova prepare` is the command I needed, thanks

Comment: It's my pleasure :)